# How to use non-ascii character string literals in firebird sql statements?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to use non-ascii character string literals in a firebird sql query.
So I used **FlameRobin** to see if it works first:
I used something like this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = 'العربية'
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 COLLATE UNICODE_CI_AI WHERE NAME = 'العربية'
```

with no success. Because I have declared **NAME** using **UTF8** Character Set and **UNICODE_CI_AI** Collation.

from this referential url link: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-appx06-charsets.html

FlameRobin throws an error about the syntax, it actually don't understand : 'العربية' string.
So I decided to change the database administration tool with **Firebird Maestro** to do the test, this tool now accepts these kind of non-ascii character string literals, but it is not doing the filter properly.

How can this issue be solved?

**NB: I am using firebird v2.5**

Comment: Which connection character set did you use in FlameRobin?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I used NONE, without noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird uses a connection character set to know how string values need to be encoded. The default is `NONE` which means that no specific character set conversion is applied, and exact behavior varies per tool/client, but in general clients will apply the system default character set to convert between byte values and strings.

You need to specify connection character set UTF8 when connecting from FlameRobin, and your query will work

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = 'العربية'
```

If you don't specify a connection character set, then connection character set NONE is applied, and as a result string values will be interpreted in the platform default encoding (which on Windows is not utf8, but for example windows-1252).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use literals. Don't put data into the query text, put it outside of query as "parameters".

It has a number of benefits, like more reliable parsing, more type-checking, more safety and often more speed (you can prepare query once, and then run it many times only changing parameters value).

How you code the parameters in SQL queries depends upon the library you use in your programming language for connecting to Firebird. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for some examples. The following are three often used conventions to try:

- `SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = ?`  -- natively supported by Firebird, index-based access to parameters
- `SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = :NAME_PARAM` -- BDE / Delphi style
- `SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME = @NAME_PARAM` -- MS SQL / .Net style

I do not know which flavours are supported in Flame Robin and Maestro.
IB Expert uses Delphi libraries, hence using #2 option.
Java-written programs tend to use #1 option.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel UTF-8 prefix and HEX literals would work too. But it is fragile and size-limited. Better to avoid problems from start than slalom between them.

Comment: Character set introducers don't always work though: they only work correctly if the byte sequence between the start and end quote are actually in the specified character set. If you are using a programming language or client that converts the entire query string to bytes using the connection character set (or the platform default for NONE), then that doesn't work. Character set introducers only work if you manually encode the query string in bytes (or to produce the right bytes).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I said "HEX Literals", you now said "if you manually encode the query string in bytes" - isn't it the same ?

Comment: I was talking about character set introducers. You could generate the query string to bytes by using different character sets for individual parts, or by doing something like `_win1250'æ'` when using connection character set WIN1252, would produce the correct bytes for `ć` or `_win1251'æ'` would yield `ж` because those are all 0xE6 in bytes. In other words: not really a practical thing to do compared to using valid literals in the right connection character set.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and I was talking about a combination of introducers with those very plain bytes - hex literals. As shown here: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-hexbinstrings.html - that will remove the ambiguity and fragility that exists because developer can key in 'æ' in UTF8 text editor, then would pass those byte in NONE or non-Unicode connection.

Comment: Then we're not talking about the same thing. You can't combine character set introducers with hex literals (the use of `x'<hex>*'` can't be combined with `_utf8'literal'`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes you can! just open the link above to the official documentation and do the examples there in IBExpert+FB2.5 - change _win1252 to _win1251 and compare results. Maybe you are just confused by your habit to write `_utf8'literal'` with a blank between tokens omitted. However those are TWO terms, not one, and there should better be a space between those tokens, as there is in FB docs, even if the parser allows you to get away forgetting that delimiting space and recovering the tokens borderlines regardless.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that worked. Thanks, learned something new.

Comment: Well, I did not know it can work with omitted space either :-D

Answer (score 0):

For ADO.NET connections, include "**Charset=UTF8**" (by default "NONE") in the connection string. As in:

"User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=SampleDatabase.fdb;DataSource=localhost;Port=3050;Dialect=3;**Charset=UTF8**;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;"